# How to keep specified separation distance between features in printout from ArcMap?

Tags: python, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, printing, arcgis-desktop

Does anyone have a solution to select features using attribute values and print only the selection keeping a specified separation distance between the features in the printout in ArcMap.

Comment: Welcome to SE-GIS!  Would you be able to provide some more details about what you are trying to do, please?  For example, I have assumed that you are using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 and added that as a tag.  I have also taken the liberty of changing your title into a question.

Comment: I am trying to create an arcmap printing interface for a naive user. The user selects some features(polygons) from a feature class and prints the selected features. The features are spaced out in the map and not as they appear in the view.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already know how to do all but the last part for which you could try [**Disperse Markers**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000002n000000) from the **Cartography** toolbox but this requires the **Advanced** license level of ArcGIS for Desktop.

A related and answered Question is **[How to represent several points with same coordinates on map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36942/how-to-represent-several-points-with-same-coordinates-on-map)**

Comment: No, wont work.I want to separate features and not annotations in the printout.