# Splitting overlapping points with same symbology in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, overlapping-features

I'm using a basic license of ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.  I have a point feature class layer and I uploaded it twice for representing two features. First is a type of person and second is the performances level of this person. Sometimes they are overlapped.  **How can I split a bit between points of each layer so I can see all of them?**  I can't use xy offset because they have not necessarily a different symbology &and I have only basic license.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36942/how-to-represent-several-points-with-same-coordinates-on-map