# Depicting multiple point features in same location using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, overlapping-features

On a map that I am creating (in ArcGIS Desktop 10), I need to include symbols for point features that are sometimes right next to (or even on top of) each other. This, of course, creates potential for all sorts of clutter or even for some features to not be displayed at all when zooming out.

I am thinking of positioning the symbols in a neat row (or column) off to the side and having some kind of arrow point from them toward the features' actual location. Is there some kind of symbology setting for this in ArcGIS (I want to be sure that the distance between the symbols is always consistent every time this is done), or do I have to align the symbols and draw the arrow (or whatever the proper term is) by hand?

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer in this post might help: [How to represent several points with same coordinates on map?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36942/how-to-represent-several-points-with-same-coordinates-on-map)

Comment: If the features are of the same type you could use a clustering technique