# How to Batch Change X, Y Coordinate Number in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, point, coordinates

I have a huge number of points (100000 points). Some of these have the same  x,y coordinates. For example, 50 points are same in x,y  then  100 points are same in another x,y coordinates and so on. Then the points are overlaid with each other and the user can’t see all of them. What I want to do is calculate the x and y of each point automatically and add a number at the end of each x and y.

For example:

Point a:  x=65.23, y=26.76

Point b:   x=65.23, y=26.76

What I want to do is:

Point a:    x= 65.231, y=26.761

Point b:    x=65.232, y=26.762

Comment: how are these points currently stored? gdb, shp or other (csv?)

Comment: Here is a similiar topic that may be of interest, [display stacked points](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36942/how-to-represent-several-points-with-same-coordinates-on-map)

Comment: Do you have an ArcInfo level license? Have you tried the Disperse Markers tool?

Comment: Considering the number of points you're dealing with, batch changing your coordinates is probably not the best way to do this as it would probably make a mess of your map. A better way would be to add an attribute or a field that tells how many points occupy this XY location.

Comment: @Mapperz points are store in shp

Comment: @mkennedy I have Arcinfo licence level

Comment: @Mintx i want to show these in webgis .

Comment: This looks like a possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/how-to-generate-random-locations-nearby-my-location

Comment: Another possible duplicate is http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35479/is-there-a-tool-to-add-noise-to-overlapping-x-y-coordinates-so-they-are-no-lo but I like the sound of @mkennedy's [**Disperse Markers**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000002n000000) since you have ArcInfo/Advanced