# Generate random points for IDs with similar coordinates with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, random

I have a dataset which consists of IDs with addresses and coordinates (long/lat). Some of the IDs have similar coordinates. How do I generate random points for the IDs that have those similar coordinates? For example, I have 60 IDs with same long/lat and they are located within the same province. How do I use the Generate Random Points tool in ArcMap to generate 60 random points within the same province and then later create a new column to store those new coordinates?

Right now I have over 10k points in the dataset. I can map them but it looks misleading as some IDs are assigned similar coordinates for simplicity purposes - and they are all stacked on top of each other in the map.

I have the province layer, and all points are retrieved from a .csv

Comment: I think this is the same requirement as in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35479/adding-noise-to-overlapping-x-y-coordinates-so-no-longer-in-exact-same-place

Comment: Collect events will tell you where you have stacked points. For me (without using python) I would add XY field, Collect events to find duplicates, select the duplicates using select by location against the events, adjust the X & Y values by a random number (in field calculator) with an arbitrary limit then create feature class from XY table to assign points with the modified x,y.

Comment: Spatial join of existing points to calculate number of points per province, using summarise. Transfer this count to new field in polygons table, use this field in create random points dialog. Sorting of sp.joined by province field might be necessary to help with original points attribute transfer

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson how do I select the duplicates exactly?

Comment: The events (from collect events) will have a 'count' attribute, anything with a count of more than 1 is a duplicate, to select from the original use definition query on the event layer then select by location to select the original points.