# Move points to XY coordinate

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, attribute-table, xy

I have a lot of points. In the attribute table I have the coordinates(coordx / coordy).

How can I move all points, so that they are corresponding to the coordinates value in the attribute table?

Answer (score 5):

You may do this within field calculator, see blog:

[How to Update the Location of a Point Feature and Its XY Fields](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2011/12/06/how-to-update-the-location-of-a-point-feature-and-its-xy-fields/)

```
def XYsetVALUE( shape, X_value, Y_value):
   point = shape.getPart(0)
   point.X = X_value
   point.Y = Y_value
   return point

__esri_field_calculator_splitter__
XYsetVALUE ( !SHAPE!, !X_COORD!, !Y_COORD! )
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to use the [UpdateCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) in the [Python Window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm). Be sure to backup your data before executing:

```py
import arcpy

feature_class=r'C:\TEST.gdb\points' #Change path and name to fc
fieldlist=['X_field','Y_field'] #Change field names to match your data

tokens=['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class,fieldlist+tokens) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[2]=row[0] #Set row[2], which is SHAPE@X, to the value of row[0] which is the first field in fieldlist
        row[3]=row[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```